# Edit the token values submitted by webforms

Tags: webforms, tokens

I am using webform for user registration and confirmation page as profile page.
I have included the token as follows
" [submission:values:name]
[submission:values:email]
[submission:values:country]
[submission:values:date]
 "
Now the submitted values are displayed in profile page but my requirement is the user should be able to edit and save only few fields but view all fields. 
How i would include edit option for displayed data using tokens.
Please help me on this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module. From its project page:

> ... allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

Since users are entities also, it should work for any of your fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works for content types and profile types. In webforms,only for comments I guess. Because webform nodes are not retrieved in the entity list while configuring the module. If you are sure that it works ,please brief out the steps.